# Watcher is rarely auto-triggered, and does not always compile the code

Tags: phpstorm

I have a couple of sites, and on one of these, just this one, the watchers are misbehaving.

The worst one is the SCSS watcher, its set to watch current file, track only root files and trigger regardless of syntax errors.

The behavior is very weird: sometimes it auto compiles the .css file on changes. Often it does not and I have to manually compile it with a binding. However often this does not compile anything though PhpStorm activated the process. Sometimes after 3 or 5 times it successfully adds the changes. So it's very sporadic and weird.

I have tried restarting everything, clear cache and so on. The SCSS compiler works fine on my other sites.

It's run in PhpStorm with these arguments:

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Only noticable thing in idea.log when the error occurs:

```
2018-03-26 10:08:36,560 [332106460]   INFO - agnostic.FrequentEventDetector - Too many events posted, #1. Event: java.awt.event.InvocationEvent[INVOCATION_DEFAULT,runnable=TransferToEDTQueue[Apply highlighting results],notifier=null,catchExceptions=false,when=1522051716560] on sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit@3f7d6f55
```

This is a purely local installation

Comment: it would be great if you could share your idea.log file once the issue reoccurs. Are this project's files local?

Comment: Hi, Ive added from the log. And yes theyre local :)

Comment: That doesn't help unfortunately. I would suggest contacting PhpStorm support with a Help > **Compress Logs & Show in ...** archive attached